# ERROR - Command text was not set for the command object

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program to book tickets for a school performance, this section of code displays dates from a database into a list box, then it gets the selected value and checks the databse with that name for the available seats.

```
Public ds As New DataSet 'used to store the basic elements of the database
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection 'used to connect to the database
Public provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Public datafile As String = "Resources/database.accdb" 'database location and version
Public da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
Public sqlstatement As String
Public connString As String = provider & datafile
Public UserbeingEdited As String
Public sSelectedAssetType As String


 ds.Clear()
    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = "SELECT ShowDate FROM AvailableDates"
    da.Fill(ds, "Dates")

    lbxDates.ValueMember = "ShowDate"
    lbxDates.DisplayMember = "ShowDate"
    lbxDates.DataSource = ds.Tables("Dates")
    con.Close()

Private Sub lbxDates_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbxDates.SelectedValueChanged
    Dim oDataRowView As DataRowView = CType(Me.lbxDates.SelectedItem, DataRowView)
    lbxActs.Items.Clear()
    lbxActs.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("Resources/" & sSelectedAssetType & ".txt"))
    sSelectedAssetType = oDataRowView("ShowDate").ToString
    For Each btn As Control In Seating_Plan.Controls
        If checkSeats(btn.Name()) = "True" Then
            SeatCount = SeatCount + 1
        End If
    Next
```

I keep getting this error and i dont know how to fix it, please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created.
If you want to use a variable to store the SQL query creates the variable and sets its value before assigning it to OleDbDataAdapter.

```
Public ds As New DataSet 'used to store the basic elements of the database
Public con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection 'used to connect to the database
Public provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Public datafile As String = "Resources/database.accdb" 'database location and version
Public da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter 
Public sqlstatement As String
Public connString As String = provider & datafile
Public UserbeingEdited As String
Public sSelectedAssetType As String


    ds.Clear()
    con.ConnectionString = connString
    con.Open()
    sqlstatement = "SELECT ShowDate FROM AvailableDates"
    da = new OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstatement, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Dates")

    lbxDates.ValueMember = "ShowDate"
    lbxDates.DisplayMember = "ShowDate"
    lbxDates.DataSource = ds.Tables("Dates")
    con.Close()
```